# Seems like both Firefox and Safari on Mac cannot show the webpage in a full screen mode?

Tags: mac, firefox, browser, safari, fullscreen

Seems like both Firefox and Safari on Mac cannot show the webpage in a full screen mode?

On the PC, it would be F11 for Firefox or IE... but on the Mac, the F11 is for volume control (sound), and there is no

```
View -> Full Screen
```

for Firefox or Safari.  Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you need a browser window to fill your entire screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saft will do it for Safari. There is a different version for 10.4, 10.5, and 10.6 so be sure to grab the appropriate one.

http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/12402/saft

Answer (score 3):

***Firefox & Chrome:***
For both current versions (at time of post) of Firefox and Chrome in OSX, <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> invokes a full 
screen view; FF with the smother transition.

***Safari:***
Still no Safari hotkey from what I could find.  It would be useful.  An easy to convey full screen hotkey for the OS default browser would be nice, and perhaps more importantly, a consistent full screen experience across browsers (wishful thinking).

***Web designers:***
FF leaves a thin gray bar at the top and Chrome doesn't which requires extra attention to page styling details... if you happen to be designing for a full screen specific resolution... for say, a touch screen kiosk web app or custom HTML/JavaScript based presentation.

***Side note:***
I don't know when either browser implemented it, but I've been using it for a while now, even if only to filter out the little bit of application window chrome and top menu bar visual noise that OSX normally shows while I'm browsing sites.  For me, another example of a less-is-more preference.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to go Full Screen with Firefox on Mac, Safari's probably similar in this case. Although you can maximize Firefox to fit the screen. Create a new bookmark and make this the location:

```
javascript:self.moveTo(0,0); self.resizeTo(screen.availWidth,screen.availHeight);
```

clicking it should expand Firefox to fit the screen.