# How to make Safari full-screen?

Tags: macos, safari, fullscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Seems like both Firefox and Safari on Mac cannot show the webpage in a full screen mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/74042/seems-like-both-firefox-and-safari-on-mac-cannot-show-the-webpage-in-a-full-scree)

I need help, how do I get Safari browser into full screen mode? Do I need to download some extensions? Where?

Answer (score 1):

1. Wait a few months for 10.7
2. [Megazoomer](http://ianhenderson.org/megazoomer.html) - SIMBL plugin that adds (actual) full screen to most applications
3. [Glims](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/27708/glims) or [Saft](https://web.archive.org/web/20111006154917/http://haoli.dnsalias.com:80/Saft/index.html) - Safari plugins with tons of features
4. `defaults write /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Info LSUIPresentationMode -int 4` and  [How to re-sign Apple's applications once they've been modified - MacNN Forums](https://web.archive.org/web/20170505182804/http://forums.macnn.com:80/79/developer-center/355720/how-re-sign-apples-applications-once/). That'll just turn menu bar and Dock hiding on whenever Safari is active.